# Как захватить видеопоток с сайта?

Tags: ffmpeg, потоки-данных, online-video

Cкриптом (например php), и сохранять награбленные куски на сервере, без перекодировки.
Или хотя бы посоветуйте какие инструменты лучше использовать.
(за правильный ответ готов заплатить)

Comment: upd: на ютубе и тп просто лежат видеофайлы, скачать их не проблема и без апи. А у меня тут видеоПОТОК, архив записи эфира телеканала,  и нужно грабить с этого потока отрезки с определенного времени, определенной длительности.

Вот например по этой ссылке http://www.ontvtime.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view_record&id=1411&start_record=2015-04-02-14-37 запускается архив канала СТС, 2 апреля, в 14:37.

Как мне сохранить 50-секундный видос начиная с этого времени?

Answer (score 1):

функцией `$data = file_get_contents($url);` получаете видео по ссылке. Потом сохраняете его с помощью функции `file_put_contents('file_name', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

У сайтов таких как Youtube или Vimeo есть способы получить прямую ссылку на файл через API. Скачав видео - конвертируете его локально сколько хотите.